# EXCEL - Summarize hours, display with custom format, then do mathematical operation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel Online to keep track of hours I work.

The first column contains the time when I arrived, the second when I left, and the third does a simple subtraction of the two times. This works like expected, and the subtraction correctly calculates the difference in hours and minutes. I do this for every day in the month and sum up the hours at the bottom of my table.

If I just use the default formatter for the summarized cell, it will display a "random" float value, like 1.20833. I apply a custom formatter `[h]:mm:ss` and it seem to correctly display the total number of hours I was at work in the cell.

Problems arise when I attempt to do calculations on the formatted summarized cell. I would like to calculate the number of hours I have worked overtime that month. It should in theory be as simple as something like this:

```
overtime = number_of_hours_worked - (days_at_work * 7.5)
```

But I don't manage to express this in Excel. My question is: how can I extract the hours (and hopefully minutes) from my cell with a custom formatting?

See reference image below. It correctly sum up that I've worked 29 hours. Over the course of three days I should work a total of (7.5 * 3 =) 22.5 hours. The last cell should say 6.5. The formula in this cell is `=HOUR(N22)-(3*7.5)` where N22 is the summarized cell.

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you a) remove the hour function, leaving just `=n22-(3*.75)` and if that doesn't work b) give the full sum the hour function as in `=hour(n22-(3*7.5))`

Comment: If the value is `29:00:00`, like in my illustration, the first formula gives me `-21.2916667` and the last gives me just `#NUM!`.

Comment: floating point typo on a) should be:  `=n22-(3*7.5)`  <- and I think that's what you want

Comment: @mcalex I did not even notice the floating point error. I entered the formula as `=n22-(3*7.5)` and it gave me the answers written above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the formatting but the formula.

Use this:

```
=(N22*24)-(3*7.5)
```

with HOUR() you will miss any minutes.  Also HOUR only returns the hour portion and since this technically has one day and 5 hours, it only will return 5 not 29.

By multiplying the time by 24 you are turning the time into a decimal with hours as the integer and the minutes and seconds a decimal.  Any days will become 24 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current formula is saying take the hour of the day if time = 29:00 and subtract 3*7.5.  At 29:00 hours it is really 5:00 am.

You already have hours so you just want to subtract the normal time component.

```
=N22-(3*7.5)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: You are correct in that the time is actually 5am. However, I would like to treat it as _number of hours and minutes_  instead of a _time_. Like I wrote in the comment above, your solution gives me `-21.2916667` as the answer, which is incorrect.